# Проблемы с include

Tags: php

От файла `site-name/www/admin/connect/other.php` в `site-name/www/connect/db.php`, и от него к `site-name/www/config.php`, никак не получается организовать переходы сначала на уровень выше, затем на уровень ниже, а потом опять наверх...

Comment: Представьте в виде иерархии, кто кого должен инклудить.

Comment: Что за лифт - вверх-вниз? Используйте composer или хотя бы свой автозагрузчик. [Почитайте](http://goo.gl/zjEkQ1).

Comment: К каждому файлу на сайте, подключаю файл для соединения с бд. но не везде он подключается, не находит его

Comment: ../ для возврата в родительскую директорию. Например из site-name/www/admin/connect/other.php можно проинклудить config.php следующим образом: include '../config.php';

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инклюдить файлы надо всегда по абсолютному пути.
Стандартный способ получения абсолютного пути до корня сайта - переменная `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. И далее к нему уже конкатенируется путь к файлу от корня сайта.

Таким образом, путь к `db.php` нужно писать так:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/connect/db.php';
```

но при этом сначала проверить, что именно лежит в `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` и скорректировать конечный вариант при необходимости.

Подробнее про [различие относительных и абсолютных путей](http://phpfaq.ru/paths).

Answer (score 1):

Самый удобный вариант (особенно, если у Вас есть фронт контроллер, index, через который проходит любой запрос) - написать функцию, которая будет заниматься подключением. К примеру

```
<?php
    function load($path, $ext = 'php')
    {
       require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $path . '.' . $ext;
    }
 ?>
```

Это самый короткий вариант. В идеале метод может реагировать на несуществующие дирректории, вызывая или не вызывая exeption. Так же можно добавить возможность автозагрузки типа http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload.php
А продумывать переходы туда-обратно - значит написать слабо поддерживаемый код, который не поддаётся рефакторингу.